# What causes double slashes in Linux?

Tags: linux

I'm installing TCE and see double slashes ( `//` ) in the installation path. Why they are there?

```
 100% - /usr/local/games/enemy-territory//tcetest/ReadMe.rtf
 100% - /usr/local/games/enemy-territory//tcetest/changelog.rtf
 100% - /usr/local/games/enemy-territory//tcetest/ui.mp.i386.so
 100% - /usr/local/games/enemy-territory//tcetest/qagame.mp.i386.so
 100% - /usr/local/games/enemy-territory//tcetest/pak3.pk3
 100% - /usr/local/games/enemy-territory//tcetest/pak2.pk3
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happens very often and it's harmless. Double slash is interpreted like simple slash.

(see `man path_resolution` to understand the path resolution process)

Comment: Can you post any article where can i check it?

Comment: I've edited my post. The issue with double slash is not explicitly mentioned in the man page though, but you can deduce the answer.

Comment: So still, the actual question left: *why* are they there? :)

Comment: simple: programming. It is better to have it than not to and you always run it through some sort of "path.normalize()" in lang/tool of your choice. :)

Answer (score 15):

It's simply the result of concatenating paths as ordinary text strings.

For example, if you specify the destination directory including the ending slash...

```
make DESTDIR=/usr/local/games/enemy-territory/ install
```

...and the installer uses it like this:

```
$(DESTDIR)/tcetest/pak3.pk3
```

When the line above gets expanded, `$(DESTDIR)` simply will be replaced with the exact contents of the variable, resulting in:

```
/usr/local/games/enemy-territory//tcetest/pak3.pk3
```

As Stéphane mentioned in their answer, having two slashes in a path is entirely harmless, which is why most install scripts don't bother with removing them.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when, say, a variable containing a directory/path name ends with a / then another / is appended to it without checking if the variable already ends with a /, like for example:

```
# say pathvariable is "/usr/bin/"
"$pathvariable/apt" # this will result in "/usr/bin//apt"
```

It's completely harmless, since consecutive / in file/dir names are treated as a single / on pretty much all Unix systems, including Linux. Also in 99% of cases, "directory/" is the same as "directory" (with no slash at the end) ...notable exception is rsync which can be pretty finicky about it =)

Comment: Oh and also if you have a symlink pointing to a directory, a process that can read either will see "symlink" as the link itself, and "symlink/" as the directory pointed to by "symlink". Try it with 'ls' and see the difference.