# Which directory does path `//` represent in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, prompt

When I want to go back to upper level directory in Linux by typing `cd ..`, I typo-ed `cd //`. To my great surprise, no errors are reported. What's more the prompt becomes `username@hostname://$`. `ls` indicates that I'm now at root directory.

Is this a bug or a feature of the shell? If a feature, is `//` an alias of `/`? My shell is GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i686-linux-gnu).

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/q/314102/91047

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It can be considered either.

In Linux, `//` means nothing – multiple consecutive slashes get collapsed to one, *anywhere* in the path, including the beginning. Changing directory to `//` puts you in `/`, as running `readlink /proc/self/cwd` would tell; likewise, `/usr//local///bin` is collapsed to `/usr/local/bin`.

However, some other Unix-like systems, for example Cygwin or the old Apollo Domain/OS, use the `//` *prefix* for network paths such as `//fileserver/path/to/data`. POSIX allows this as well.

For various reasons, the *bash* shell tracks the current directory on its own (in addition to the OS-provided tracking) and it has code in it that prevents the initial `//` from being collapsed, to remain compatible with such systems. The "feature" is that *bash* provides more intuitive tracking of current directory, for example, when `cd`'ing into a symlink, *bash* will show you the path you expect, even though the kernel thinks otherwise. The "bug" is that *bash* permits `//` even on systems that do not use it.

Comment: Interestingly, `zsh` allows `cd //`, but is smart enough to just show `/` in the prompt string.

Comment: @BinaryZebra Bitsavers has a collection of old Unix manuals, including Apollo's – there should be plenty of examples there. The TUHS website should have something as well.

Comment: Many thanks, I found the description for // in the Bitsavers manual.

Answer (score 9):

From the POSIX pathname definition:

> A pathname may optionally contain one or more trailing slashes. Multiple successive slashes are considered to be the same as one slash.

[Source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_266)

And more precisely as grawity mentioned in his comment below, from the [4.11 chapter](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11) on Pathname Resolution:

> A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading slashes shall be treated as a single slash.

Comment: A more proper section is [4.11 Pathname Resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11) (last paragraph), since the behavior in question only appears for two *leading* slashes.

Answer (score 3):

It a kind of feature. If you've got shell script going and use `find`, for example all paths are prefixed with ./ usually. Then, if you tack that onto an actual path it becomes `/my/path/./appended/path, which resolves to /my/path/appended/path. So, if I'm not mistaken, // get's interpreted as /./ and therefore /. This is the same for if you went to /home/user//, you'd wind up in /home/user/

Answer (score 1):

I would go for prompt displaying "bug".

Either paths "/", "//", "//////////////////////", ... have the same meaning: "/".
You can add as many "/" wherever you want in an Unix path, this not change its meaning.

The "bug" is more here related to the fact that your prompt use the last valid typed in path for display, not the actual "pwd".

Funny anyway ;)

Comment: Agreed -- the `//` in the prompt is a side effect of your prompt environment variable (`$PS1`) -- how is `PS1` defined?

Comment: @DougHarris the `$PS1` variable is defined as `[\u@\h \W]\$`. Any problem with setting?

Comment: Odd. If I try that PS1, I only get one `/` when pwd = `/`. I wondered if you were doing any extra work to get the directory. Is `$PROMPT_COMMAND` set?

Comment: @DougHarris Yes, this variable is set, whose value is `echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#HOME/~}"; echo -ne "\007"`. Could you pls explain in a little bit detail? I'm not quite familiar with these two variables. Thanks.

Comment: Read the bash man page and search for `PS1` and `PROMPT_COMMAND` -- use `man bash` at your command line or [read online](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Answer (score 1):

Its a Feature and all multiple // will be replaced to one single /

Its useful if you have variables with paths like the example at the end.
So your cd wouldn't get any error and you don't have to change the workspace 
variable.

```
MY_WORKSPACE=/home/your_username/workspace/
MY_NEW_PROJECT=$MY_WORKSPACE/my_proj/
cd $MY_NEW_PROJECT
```

the complete content of the project variable is

```
/home/your_username/workspace//my_proj/
```